# Where is the main character named in Hotline Miami?

Tags: hotline-miami

On the Wikia for *Hotline Miami*, the player character of the first game is referred to as Jacket. I just beat the first game the other day, and I don’t think this name was ever actually mentioned in it.

From where does this name originate? <s>Is it official, or made up by fans</s> Where was it first used by fans?

Comment: The game’s definitely on-topic—there is a thing with zombies just randomly showing up in a lot of the game.

Comment: "*Set in 1989 Miami, the game revolves primarily around an unnamed silent protagonist—dubbed "Jacket" by fans*"; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotline_Miami. So it seems the name is just a fan creation

Comment: The creator refers to the two characters as "Jacket and Biker" on his twitter.  https://twitter.com/cactusquid/status/575742028304269313